# Проблема с событием CellValueChanged TreeList

Tags: c#, visual-studio, devexpress

В дерево загружаю объекты

```
private void FillTree(List<Theme> thems)
{
    Root.Nodes.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < thems.Count; i++)
    {
        var theme = thems[i];
        var node = Thems.AppendNode(new object[] { theme }, Root);
        for (int j = 0; j < theme.Questions.Count; j++)
        {
            var question = theme.Questions[j];
            Thems.AppendNode(new object[] { question }, node);
        }
    }
}
```

Когда пытаюсь изменить текст в ноде(по F2) , то хочу изменить свойство объекта которое там сидит, но в событии `CellValueChanged`  объект obj(Theme) имеет не мой тип а `string`.

```
  private void Thems_CellValueChanged(object sender, DevExpress.XtraTreeList.CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Node != null)
        {
            var obj = (Thems.GetDataRecordByNode(e.Node) as ArrayList)[0];
            if (obj != null)
            {
                if (obj.GetType() == typeof(Theme))
                    ((Theme)obj).Caption = e.Value.ToString();
            }
        }

    }
```

В событии `FocusedNodeChanged` переменная `obj` до изменения имеет мой тип , а после тип `string`

```
   private void Thems_FocusedNodeChanged(object sender, DevExpress.XtraTreeList.FocusedNodeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Node == null)
            return;
        var obj = (Thems.GetDataRecordByNode(e.Node) as ArrayList)[0];
}
```

Перезатирается он что ли.
Как изменить при редактировании свойство моего объекта?

Comment: а какой тип должен быть?

Comment: @CuprumBur должен быть тот тип объекта который я туда добавляю(`Theme` или `Question` )

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо было для своих объектов реализовать интерфейс `IVirtualTreeListData` и назначит свойству `DataSourse` корневой элемент своей структуры либо же воспользоваться событиями дерева 
`VirtualTreeGetChildNodes, VirtualTreeGetCellValue, VirtualTreeSetCellValue`
Ответ [тут](https://documentation.devexpress.com/windowsforms/5561/Controls-and-Libraries/Tree-List/Examples/Data-Binding/How-to-Implement-a-Tree-Structure-for-a-Business-Object) и [тут](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/5562/Controls-and-Libraries/Tree-List/Examples/Data-Binding/How-to-Load-Data-Dynamically-via-Events)